# How to sound confident but not cocky?

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, formatting, structure

I am working on this slogan, and it comes out like this.

> On the road to success.

What I mean by that is that I have positioned myself to accomplish something, but while I am not there yet, I have entered the road to success.

I am not sure if the sentence above translates into that meaning, or it comes out as arrogant. In the sense that he only cares about his own success and not the well being of others.

I also feel this sentence is incomplete, and not sure what to add to have a complete sentence.

Comment: The sentence as it stands is incomplete, but slogans oftentimes aren't complete sentences. If presented in the correct context, like directly beneath a company logo or on an advertising brochure, you may not have to add anything. Could you provide more detail about how you plan to use this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as whether it will sound confident or cocky I would think depends more on the context surrounding this sentence than the sentence itself. That being said, for the content of the sentence how about something along the lines of the individual can see the end goal, even more so can visualize the path connecting him to it. This conveys that while the individual knows what to do, he's not saying it's superior or even well-planned, thus avoiding sounding arrogant.

Example: "After experiencing X, I now understand what needs to be done next. The finish line manifested before me as tangible as the earth under my feet: I must do Y."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you prehaps provide some example.

Comment: Great example. Would there be a way to simplify your example so that it communicates with less words, and so that someone who is not fluent in english can comprehend the meaning.

Comment: I can certainly try ;) . How about "The path from where I am to where I need to be was paved at that very moment." Sorry if it doesn't apply, pretty much shooting in the dark without context.